# Question about Integral with exponential function

Tags: probability, integration

Please refer to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ58x.png) below. I would like to ask why the highlighted part would be gone in step $2$ ? What calculation involved making it $0$ ? Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}-xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x}{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-1}{xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}=0 $$

$$ \lim_{x\to-\infty}-xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-x}{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-1}{xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}=0$$

So, the highlighted term in your question vanishes, because the infinite limits of the term are zero. Note, we used L'Hôpital's Rule to find this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand when we come across certain situation in calculating limit of a function, we would use L'Hôpital's Rule. But I would like to ask why would we apply L'Hospital Rule here when we are not doing limit.

Comment: We must evaluate a limit, because we can not simply plug in $\infty$ or $-\infty$ into a function, since $\infty$ is not a number. So, to evaluate the expression, an infinite limit is needed.

Comment: ah! I get it! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. If this answer is acceptable to you be sure to mark it as accepted, so the question is officially answered.

Comment: sorry I am new to this forum. Where can I find the Accepted button?

Comment: There should be a check mark next to the up vote button. Try to do this in general- it lets us know if our answer is good enough.

Comment: yay I think i click the check mark already! thanks again!